# How to make a page full accesible by iFrame

Tags: php, html, apache, iframe

The page 1 works an loads well into an iframe, but when I try to access through JS I got this error.

`Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://domain1.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame`  (the frame that is trying to access is in "https://domain2.com" )

I'have the full access in both servers, and I already tried with **'X-Frame-Options' & header**  **'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header**, even tried to remove the X-Frame-Options header.

I don't know what else do.

Comment: `X-Frame-Options` is for whether the browser is allowed to _display_ the content inside (i)frames, and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` applies to cross-domain HTTP requests. Neither of those have anything to do with accessing elements inside the iframe’s document - which the _Same Origin Policy_ simply prevents you from doing, if the origins differ.

Comment: Ok, then what else can I try?

Comment: You could start by properly explaining, what actual _problem_ you are trying to solve here in the first place. Then we can maybe tell, if there’s another way, or whether what you want is simply impossible to begin with.

Comment: Sure, thanks for reply, want to get the height of an embed page by iframe to change the height of  iframe tag container each time the embed site changes its url. But each time I want to access the embed site, I got this error.

Comment: That is only possible, if the other party actively supports this, you’re gonna need their “help”. The iframe would have to report its own content height to the parent page via something like `postMessage`, and then the parent page can adjust the iframe element’s height. Check with the provider of your widget, whether they offer anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you not use iframes for your use case.  Instead, fetch the content that you want to insert into the page through an XHR call, and insert it directly into the page.  This only works if you're inserting your own content that you control.

That way, the content will actually be in the DOM of your main web page, and the outer elements around your content will grow in height automatically, subject to your CSS overflow setup and that kind of thing.

Here's an example of how I load a central footer from a corporate web site onto lots of web sites from the same company:

```
...

  <div id='lazyFooter'></div>

</body>

<script>
function footerCallback(json_data){
  document.getElementById('lazyFooter').outerHTML = json_data[0];
}
window.onload = function() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'https://footers.ourcompany.com/footer.min.json'
  script.async = true;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
</script>
```

This example uses JSONP, so the file that you load needs to be formatted as a Javascript function:

```
footerCallback(["\ <style class=\"embed\">\n\
@font-face{font-family:'Darby Sans ...  </style><footer class=\" 
... </div>\n\ </footer>\n\ "]);
```

If you're embedding someone else's content and it's not formatted as a JSONP response, then you have (at least) two options:

1. Use an iframe instead and deal with the Javascript hassles to set the height.  (Ugly, not portable across browsers.)
2. Deploy a simple server-side microservice with an AWS Lambda function or something, for fetching the third-party content on the server side and packaging it as a JSONP response that you can embed in your page.  Or, if you can run that microservice on the same domain as your site, then you don't need to worry about JSONP and you can simply proxy bare HTML from the third-party site through the microservice to your XHR call.